# Inconsistency related to the definition of net/directed set in Kelley's General Topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, order-theory

I've been confused about the definition of **directed set** in John L. Kelley's book "General Topology" (1), and feel inconsistency in multiple relevant places.

Overall, I feel that in the following sentence on [p.65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKms6.png)

> A binary relation $\geq$ **directs** a set *D* if *D* is non-void and ...

the symbol "$\geq$" should have been "$\leq$". Such change would make it consistent with other textbooks, such as Munkres (2) and Willard (3).

More importantly, Kelley seems to be inconsistent with himself, e.g.,

1. in the paragraph right below the definition of **directs** on [p.65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKms6.png), it says

> We say that *m* follows *n* in the order "$\geq$" and ... iff $m \geq n$

while earlier on [p.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUKvG.png) he said

> If $<$ is an ordering and $x<y$, then ... $y$ follows $x$

which seems more natural to me.

The inconsistency between the two places is that if we treat $<$ and $\geq$ as a more abstract relation $R$, then on [p.65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKms6.png) he says $m$ follows $n$ if $\mathbf{mRn}$, while on [p.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUKvG.png) he says $m$ follows $n$ if $\mathbf{nRm}$ (I made substitution $x\rightarrow n$ and $y\rightarrow m$ to make the contrast more clear).

2. In the paragraph that follows, there is another example:

> ... the set $\omega$ of non-negative integers are directed by $\geq$. Observe that 0 is a member of $\omega$ which follows every other member in the order $\leq$.

From the context I feel that the $\geq$ in the above text should be interpreted as the usual ordering of natural numbers, i.e., $j \geq i$ means $j$ is bigger than or equal to $i$ in the usual sense. If we follow this interpretation, then I do not see how the property of 0 explains why $\omega$ is directed by $\geq$. In contrast, the property of 0 would explain why $\omega$ is directed by $\leq$.

I've also tried hard with alternative interpretations in multiple places, but could not make Kelley's exposition consistent with itself. Anybody has a clue?

(1) Kelley, *General Topology*, Dover edition 0-486-81544-7 
(2) Munkres, *Topology: a first course*, Prentice-Hall 1975, 0-13-925495-1 
(3) Willard, *General Topology*, Dover edition, 0-486-43479-6

Attached are the pictures of [p.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUKvG.png) and [p.65](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKms6.png) from the Springer edition of GTM27 0-387-90125-6, which is the same as (1).

Comment: I think he wants to say that *$\omega$ follows*, not *$0$ follows*. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thank you Sigur. Are you saying that the word "which" in the sentence refers to the $\omega$ right before it? If so, why mention $0$ at all? And even worse, even if we follow the convention of von Neuman for cardinal numbers as the definition of integers here, i.e., $0:=\phi$, $1:=\{\phi\}$, etc., we only have "... $\omega$ (which) follows every other member in the order $\mathbf{\geq}$", not $\mathbf{\leq}$ as written in the textbook. Please note that the textbook says "We say that m follows n in the order "≥" and ... iff m≥n"

Comment: Also in case you meant a typo: $0$ should have been $\omega$, then the sentence would become "Observe that $\omega$ is a member of ω which follows every other member in the order ≤", which does not make much sense either.

Answer (score 1):

A directed set has as its primitive relation $\ge$. If we replace it by $F$ to be neutral and pronounce $nFm$ as $n$ follows $m$, the axioms for a directed set say

1. If $m$ follows $n$ and $n$ follows $p$ then $m$ follows $p$, or $$\forall m,n,p \in D: (mFn \land nFp) \to mFp$$
2. Every $m$ follows itself. Or $$\forall m \in D: mFm$$
3. For any two $m,n$ we can find a $p$ that follows both of them, or $$\forall m,n \in D: \exists p \in D: pFm \land pFn$$

I think this is quite clear, so far. 
Now it gets a bit confusing because $x \ge y$ already an alternative symbol for $y \le x$, when $\le$ is a partial order. But at least the word "follows" is used the same way; at page 13 if $x \le y$ , $y$ follows $x$, which corresponds to page 65's $y \ge x$ as well.

The remark on $\omega$ is true as it stands. He purposefully inverts the order to illustrate that the symbol doesn't always has the obvious meaning:

So he has $\omega =\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ and he defines (using my symbol $F$ for clarity) that $mFn$ iff $m \le n$, where $\le$ is the usual ordering on $\omega$. Then axioms 1. and 2. are clear because the usual ordering on $\omega$ is transitive and reflexive. 3. follows from the fact that whatever $m,n$ are we can always take $p=0$: $0Fm$ because $0 \le m$ in the usual order. By reversing the order (so now $1$ "follows" $2$ in the directed set relation, etc.) the directed set in question has a "maximum", which "follows" all elements, to wit $0$. So this example serves (I think) to warn the reader that "follows" in a directed set doesn't always mean the same as an already defined notion "follows" from a partial order. It's meant to make you think and warn that "$\ge$" is not always what you think it is. He still uses $\ge$ in directed sets and not the boring $F$ I used, because it evokes the right idea that the left element in the directed-order relation is "further along". This doesn't have to be literally true, as we saw using $\omega$ or the trivial example that $nFm$ is true for all pairs ("any set is directed.."), where there is no "direction" in an intuitive sense. These examples all illustrate that a notion of directed-ness can be very general. The "direction reversal" is also seen in his example of the "set of finite subsets of a set" where $A \ge B$ ($A$ follows $B$) means that $B \subseteq A$; here the confusion is less as we don't write inclusion as $\le$, so it's not confusing symbols. Axiom 3. shows what the "direction" is, and this axiom distinguishes a directed set from a partial order.

If a set $(A,\le_A)$ is already a partial order, then if it's directed "naturally" in the sense that a directed set $(A,\ge)$ is just defined as $nFm$ or $n \ge m$ iff $m \le_A n$, then Fremlin (in his book Consequences of Martin's Axiom, where posets play a central role) says that $A$ is "upwards-directed", whereas if $nFm$ or $n \ge m$ is defined as $n \le_A m$ (as in Kelley's $\omega$) the set is "downward-directed". I quote from page 4 paragraph 11G(b):

> It's not customary to distinguish, for example, between "upwards-ccc" and "downwards-ccc" partially ordered sets; most authors fix on one of these (usually, I think, downwards) and call it simply "ccc". The difficulty with this is that many partially ordered sets come to us with a natural orientation. (Consider, for instance, 11F above; or the cases where our partially ordered set $P$ is a collection of sets ordered by $\subseteq$, as in 32B and 33E below.) There is no logical difficulty in declaring, if necessary, that '$A \le B$ iff $B \subseteq A$'; but I find that following the subsequent arguments is like drinking a glass of water while hanging upside-down .I think it easier to take the trouble to use a language which can itself perform the necessary inversions.[..]

TLDR: I don't think Kelley is inconsistent, he's just giving an illustrative example to clarify. I do think Fremlin has a good point here, though.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, Henno!

Comment: @ALife I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Regarding the inconsistency between p.13 & p.65, an important point is the underlying ordering. My understanding is that in both places the author tries
to define "follows" with respect to the underlying (order) relation given by phrase like "in the order xxx". Although p.13 and p.65 appear to be "consistent" in that p.13
says $x\leq y \Leftrightarrow y$ follows $x$", and p.65 says $y\geq x \Leftrightarrow y$ follows $x$, as you pointed out, they have different underlying
ordering (p.13 $<$, while p.65 $\geq$). In fact, such "consistency" on the surface actually indicates **in**consistency.

Comment: This is also in my original post what I meant by "... if we treat $<$ and $\geq$ as a more abstract relation $R$, then on p.65 he says $m$ follows $n$ if
$\mathbf{mRn}$, while on p.13 he says $m$ follows $n$ if $\mathbf{nRm}$" with the common underlying order (the abstract $R$).  Sorry I had to add my comments separately due to the length restriction.

Comment: Regarding the $\omega$-example, my understanding is that in the sentence "... $\omega$ ... (is) directed by $\geq$", $\geq$ should
be interpreted as a relation **specific to this example**, since that's how it goes in the two subsequent examples ($\subset$ and
$\supset$), and something like "xxx (a specific set) is directed by an abstract relation (could be anything)" does not make much
sense to me. In addition, in the sentence that follows, "Observe ... in the order $\leq$", my interpretation of the $\leq$ is the
inverse of the "$\geq$" in the preceding sentence.

Comment: With the above interpretations, I do not see how the second sentence justifies the first: the first sentence says that
$\omega$ is directed by an order, say $R_\omega$ (the relation specific to this $\omega$-example), while the second sentence says that
$0$ follows every other member in the inverse of $R_\omega$, which means "(every other member) $R_\omega$ (member $0$), opposite to what's
needed by the definition.

Comment: Clarification: $R_\omega$ in the above comments represents "$\geq$" in the textbook (in the first sentence), and the inverse of $R_\omega$ represents "$\leq$" in the textbook (in the second sentence).

Comment: Regarding your answer related to the $\omega$-example, your interpretation "... warn that $\geq$ is not always what you think it is" seems reasonable to me in general, assuming the "$\geq$ here is just an alternative symbol for your $F$. However, such interpretation seems not applicable to this example, because in my understanding the $\geq$ in the $\omega$-example in the textbook should be 1) specific to this example and 2) consistent with the $\leq$ in the subsequent sentence (i.e., they are inverse to each other). This is also what my earlier comments at 17:12:04Z meant.

Comment: @ALife in this book “directed by $\ge$” has the meaning like I wrote as $mFn$ ( pronounced as “$m$ follows$n$ always) and is independent on how it is defined. So it could mean larger finite set, or smaller natural number, or smaller neighbourhood etc. For partial orders the old meaning of “follows” is still used in the meaning on page 13. There is no inconsistency just another meaning of “ follows” depending on whether we are talking about s directed set or a partially ordered one.

Comment: @@Henno thanks for the follow-up. Isn't the "$\geq$" in the definition of "directs" a binary relation that already existed (defined earlier/elsewhere) **before** the definition of "directs/directed", and before the definition of "follows"? The first sentence in the section on p.65 says "A binary relation $\geq$ **directs** a set $D$ if $D$ is non-void and ..."

Comment: Put it another way, don't you think there is always an underlying binary relation whenever we say "a *follows* b"?

Comment: @ALife Yes, there is in a directed set a relation called “follows” which is denoted by $\ge$ in all cases. Also if we happen to have another relation on the same set already; this doesn't matter. Context tells us which we mean.

Comment: @@Henno your comments above seem to be confirming the inconsistency between p.13 and p.65 that I listed in my original post: on p.65, for a set with binary relation "follows" (or $R$ or $\geq_f$" or $R_f$, or whatever notation), $x$ follows $y$ is the same thing as $xRy$, while one p.65, for a set with binary relation "$<$" (or $R$ or whatever), $x$ follows $y$ means $yRx$, the opposite. Note that we are not talking about any specific relation and then another specific relation.

Comment: In case I misunderstood you or missed your points, to be even more clear,  given a set $X$ with binary relation R and $xRy$ for $x, y\in X$, do you say "$x$ follows $y$ in the order R" or $y$ follows $x$ in the order R"? I think both p.13 and p.65 are supposed to give us an answer, but they will give different answers. What do you think?

Comment: @ALife you say $x$ follows $y$ if $R$ is the relation in a directed set and $x$ precedes $y$  if $R$ is an order relation in its usual form $<$ or $\le$ or $x$ follows $y$ if $R$ is an inverse order relation. No problem, but the context matters.

Comment: I understood you tried to say "context matters" and it's ok (although not ideal), but "context matters" does not mean arbitrary interpretation. Your comments above could have many different interpretations, esp., given the use of $<$ and $\leq$ (are they necessary), so I am not sure what's your answer(s) to my question above: which follows which?

Comment: @ALife $x \ge y$ is $x$ follows $y$ in both cases. Ordered and directed.

Comment: thanks. Can I rewrite your comments as "'$xRy$' means 'x follows y' in both cases" to avoid ambiguity?

Comment: @ALife no, not always. $R$ must be $\ge$ or $>$ to be pronounced as $x$ follows $y$.

Comment: so which case is no? if we only have a binary relation $R$ and $xRy$ and know nothing else, what's your answer in both cases?

Comment: @Alife $xRy$ has no generic pronunciation, except $x$ R $y$ or $x$ has a relation to $y$. Kelley doesn't claim one either. Only for orders where $\le$ is used there is another term, and $x \ge y$ for orders is a synomym (by definition!) of $y \le x$. etc.

Comment: @@Henno On p.13, the symbol "<" is defined as generic: "A relation < orders a set $X$ iff it is transitive on $X$". Then the subsequent sentence says "If < is an ordering and $x<y$, then ... $y$ follows $x$ ...". In other words, in the above two sentences the "<" can also be replaced by $R$ everywhere (or whatever letter/symbol), e.g., "A relation $R$ orders a set $X$ iff it is transitive on $X$. If $R$ is an ordering and $xRy$, then ... $y$ follows $x$ ..". As for the the terms "follows", given that you interpret it as non-generic, it becomes clear that p.13 and p.65 are inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

Given the length restriction to comments, I hope what follows can help clarify why I think the $\omega$-example on p.65 is inconsistent with itself and/or with the definition earlier on the same page.

I think if $\omega$-example is stated in the opposite way, it would be consistent, and here is my version of the statement, followed by the proof/explanation.

**Statement**: The set $\omega$ is directed by $\leq$ because $0$ is a member of $\omega$ which follows every other member in the
order $\leq$. (Note that in my statement $\omega$ is directed by $\leq$ while the textbook says $\omega$ is directed by $\geq$.) 
 
**Proof**: we try to follow the definition of **directs** (directed set) given on p.65. Since we are trying to prove that
"$\mathbf{\omega}$" is "directed by $\leq$", the set $D$ and the abstract $\geq$ symbol in the definition (or $F$ in Hennon's
terminology) would become $\omega$ and $\leq$ **everywhere**, respectively.

(a) and (b) are obvious. 
(c) we want to show that $(\forall m, n \in \omega)((\exists p \in \omega) (p\leq m \wedge p\leq n))$. Since "$0$ is a member of $\omega$ which follows every other member in the order $\leq$," $0$ is such a $p$:

$$(\forall m, n \in \omega)(0\leq m \wedge 0\leq n)$$

$\blacksquare$

I agree that the "$\geq$" in the **definition** could be anything, including a concrete $\leq$, as Hennon stated/implied in his/her answer:

> He purposefully inverts the order to illustrate that the symbol doesn't always has the obvious meaning:

but when it boils down to a specific example (e.g., the $\omega$-example or the subsequent $\subset$-example), whatever symbol used needs to stand for
a concrete order.

In other words, the $\geq$ in the definition (abstract, $F$ in Hennon's terminology, for now written as $\geq_F$) and the $\geq$ in the sentence "...
$\omega$ ... (is) directed by $\geq$" (concrete, for now written as $\geq_\omega$) are **different** and **should be** different: the former could be anything, while the latter should have a specific
meaning and actually needs to be consistent with the $\leq$ in the subsequent sentence "Observe $0$ is ... in the order $\leq$", i.e., $\geq_\omega$ means the opposite of $\leq$. Unfortunately, with this setting the subsequent sentence does not justify the statement "... $\omega$ ... (is) directed by $\geq$" and that's the reason why I think changes are needed, as given at the beginning of this answer.

Comment: $\omega$ is directed by $\le$ means : $\omega$ is directed by $\ge$ where $x \ge y$ iff $x \le_\omega y$. But this is why Fremlin has its alternative terminology.

Comment: but if so, then where is the meaning of $\leq_\omega$ from? "$\leq_\omega$" must have already been defined somewhere, or can be inferred from the statement "$\omega$ is directed by $\leq$", right?

Comment: $\le_\omega$ is the natural order on the natural numbers (as defined in the set theory part). It's not inferred from a statement about directedness @Alife, while $\ge$ is the "follows" relation for a directed structure (defined here).

Comment: If you have been following my convention with the subscript $\omega$, then "$\leq_\omega$" stands for the binary relation specific (concrete) to $\omega$ in the context, and if so, there is a gap between this $\leq_\omega$ and "the natural order on the nature numbers" that needs to filled up. In other words, we need to state that $\leq_\omega$ (concrete $\leq$ for $\omega$) is "the natural order on the natural numbers", unless it can be inferred. It seems that you unconsciously changed the semantic meaning of $\leq_\omega$, which is critical for discussion like this.

Comment: Also I am not so sure if you used $\leq_\omega$ on purpose or not, but the $\omega$-example on p.65 states "... $\omega$ ... (is) directed by $\geq$" (**not** $\leq$ or $\leq_\omega$), and I replaced $\geq$ by $\geq_\omega$ to emphasize that the $\geq$ in the text is a concrete binary relation (that needs to be defined). I think following what the textbook says will make the discussion more focused, with less confusion and ambiguity.

Comment: I am not so sure if I understood your words properly, but regardless of "$\geq$" being the "follows" relation or not (however you call/interpret), it's firstly **a binary relation** as stated at the beginning of the definition: "A binary relation $\geq$ **directs** ...".

Comment: At the top level, I can sense what Kelley and you are trying to say, but we are talking about math: we need to strictly follow the definition and statements whenever possible. This is particularly true given a subject of general topology with many subtleties and the overall clear and rigorous exposition by Kelley throughout the book.

Answer (score 0):

I now think (on second reading) that Kelley is giving two examples in those two sentences:

> The real numbers as well as the set $\omega$ of non-negative integers are directed by $\ge$.

This is true, I think we can agree on that. We have a linear order which is always directed because $\max(x,y) \ge x$ and $\max(x,y) \ge y$ and $\max(x,y)$ always exists in a linear order. The example with $\omega$ is especially important as it shows that a net is a generalisation of a sequence. It's two examples in one go, one for sequences, one for "long sequences" (indexed by reals)

Then the second example:

> Observe that $0$ is a member of $\omega$ which follows every other member in the order $\le$.

This is not literally true, of course, but it **is** true here because the direction is reversed: $\le =\, \le_\omega\, = F$, as I defined $F$ (follows) in my earlier answer. So $0 \le n$ is true in $\omega$ so $0 \ge n$ pronounced as "$0$ follows $n$" is true in *the directed set*. So we have an example of a linear order with a minimum and when we interpret the natural $\le_\omega$ as the $\ge$ symbol of a directed set (this always has this symbol, as Kelley makes clear, I think) we get the reverse order example, different from the one (or two) in the sentence before.

Note that this interpretation is consistent with the next one:

> It is also noteworthy that the family of all neighborhoods of a point in a topological space is directed by $\subset$ (the intersection of two neighborhoods is a neighborhood **which follows both** (my emphasis) in the ordering $\subset$.

So $N_1 \cap N_2 \ge N_2$ and $N_1 \cap N_2 \ge N_2$ (the intersection follows both) (as $N_1 \cap N_2 \subset N_2$ and $N_1 \cap N_2 \subset N_2$). This speaks for my interpretation in the second example as $\ge$ (direction) is synonymous with $\le$ (order).

The next to last example is again consistent:

> The family of all finite subsets of a set is, on the other hand, directed by $\supset$.

This is clear because we can take the union of two finite sets $F$ and $G$ and
see $F \cup G \ge F$ and $F \cup G \ge G$ (using the synonyms $\ge$ (direction) = $\supset$ (order)).

And trivially (to see any set can be made a directed set, so that there is no set of all subnets of a net, but a class):

> Any set is directed by agreeing that $x \ge y$ for all members $x$ and $y$, so that each element follows both itself and any other element.

IMHO this hammers in the notion that

> We **always** use $\ge$ for the relation in a **directed set**, no matter what other structure the set we're working on already had, and we always pronounce $x \ge y$ (for a directed set) as "$x$ follows $y$".

There is no contradiction with p.13 because there he is talking about an order ("merely" a transitive relation), and later he's talking about a "directed set", a separate notion. Note that  $x \ge y$ is pronounced "$x$ follows $y$" in either case.